# How to resolve SQLite SUM() between Dates using Delphi?

Tags: sql, sqlite, delphi, sum

i have an SQLite database with the fellowing fileds: (Fullname, Phone, StartDate, Montant) and i want to calculate the SUM of the field "Montant" who is between a range of dates like (SUM(Montant) between 01/01/2018 and 03/01/2018).

the image bellow describe my problem:
the SQL return a wrong result 200 but the correct is 120 for dates between 01/01/2018 and 02/01/2018.
[SQL return a wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnXd7.png)

anothe problem is when i put a StartDate bigger or after the database date, a float exception raise like in picture.
The startdate is 06/01/2018 and the enddate is 10/01/2018.
[Exception of float occured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFKbf.png)

in Absolute Database return Zero and no exception, but SQLite return exception because he found empy field.

help please.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output in the question itself. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Comment: Your question is v. unclear.  a) What date format are you using in AbsDB and SqlLite, e.g. dd/mm/yyyy and have you checked that it is the same for both?  b) In any case, it is rarely a good idea to use `Between` in Sql queries, especially using date columns.  F.i. are you absolutely positive that in both databases, the query will include rows whose StartDate is equal to the upper value of the `Between`?  It is usually better to require that the later date is before the day **after** the upper value in the range.

Answer (score 0):

As you describe it the answer is "20".
What you are referring to with an answer of 120 is:
=> date1 and < date2 -- so which is it?
i.e equal to or greater than date 1 and less than date 2.
hth

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, after hard work and test i fount the solution and i will share it to all Delphi developers:

```
function _sqlSelectSumBetweenDates(aQuery: TFDQuery; aTable: string; aSumField: string; aField: string; aDate1: string; aDate2: string): Real;
var d1, d2: string;
begin
d1 := _SQLiteDateFormat(StrToDate(aDate1));
d2 := _SQLiteDateFormat(StrToDate(aDate2));
try
aQuery.SQL.Clear();
aQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT SUM(' + aSumField + ') FROM ' + aTable + ' WHERE ' + aField + ' BETWEEN ' + QuotedStr(d1) + ' AND ' + QuotedStr(d2);
aQuery.Active   := True;
Result          := aQuery.Fields[0].AsFloat;
except
Result := 0;
end;
end;

function _SQLiteDateFormat(aDate: TDate): string;
begin
Result := FormatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD', aDate);
end;
```

know you can call the function:

```
function _sqlSelectSumBetweenDates(aQuery: TFDQuery; aTable: string; aSumField: string; aField: string; aDate1: string; aDate2: string): Real;
```

and replace the variables with your values.